# How to know if a RG fixed point is attractive or repulsive?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

Assuming that I have the beta functions and fixed point solutions of a particular model how can I determine whether the fixed points are attractive or repulsive in each direction?

Comment: See e.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_stability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is essentially to expand the RG-equations around the fixpoint so you can actually solve them. Assume we are given a collection of couplings

$g_i$ with fixed points $g_i^*$ in combination with a set of equations (the beta functions) $\lambda \frac{dg_i}{d\lambda} = \beta_i(g_j)$

Now define $\delta g_i = g_i^* - g_i$ and expand $\beta_i$ to linear order such that
$\lambda \frac{d\delta g_i}{d\lambda} = B_{ij} \delta g_j + \mathcal{O}(\delta g^2)$
where $B_{ij}$ is the matrix of taylor coefficients.

You can now look at the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of this matrix $v_i, \gamma_i$. Plugging one of these vectors into the set of equations we find

$\lambda\frac{d v_i}{d\lambda} = \gamma_i v_i $
which you can trivially solve or just realize that the direction of flow along the eigendirections of the fixpoint corresponds to the sign of the eigenvalue such that any negative eigenvalues represent a flow away from the fp, with positive corresponding to flow towards the fp. (This is just seen by solving the differential equation)

The only tricky thing here is the existence of these Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues, as there my not be the same number of Eigenvectors as directions in space. I'm not sure how to deal with this generally.